# Overlay div over image and fit the width

Tags: css, image, css-position, tumblr

How do I get the ad to be 100% of the width of the image when the image is hovered,

Here is the issue:

http://whotheyrewearing.tumblr.com/

The image could be any width but I don't want it to overflow the image, I used absolute positioning with left and right set to 0 to make it stretch, but it stretches to the width of the containing div not the imgWrap span.

Comment: Post relevant code on your question.

Comment: Do you want a JavaScript answer or CSS only? Can you change your markup to match suggestions? Is the image present as an inline element, block, or some other (float, absolutely position)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, if the img element is floating then its parent won't automatically get the size. Also, as I see imgWrap is a div not a span, making it use as much width as possible, being set to a display: block.

You should have your img element wrapped inside another element with display inline or inline-block. That will make sure the wrapping element takes the size of its children. Give it a position relative, then you could place the caption with a position absolute and set it to use 100% width.

Hope it help. Good luck!

P.S.

Checked your code, here's what I think you should do.
Add the following to your div.imgWrap:

```
display: inline-block;
position: relative;
```

I think that in your case it would be enough.

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like :

```
<a href="#">
 <img src="image_path">
 <span>Your text add</span>
</a>
```

and css:

```
a {
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}

span {
    background: #000;
    bottom: 0;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    display: none;
    max-height: 100px; /* same as the biggest image*/
    opacity: 0.65;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0 2px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100px; /* same as the image*/
}

a:hover span {
    display: block;
}
```

with its respective class,